# How to Find Out-of-Order Characters in a String

Tags: python, string, sorting

This question relates to a current issue I'm running into at work but since it is pretty broad, I'm trying to phrase this as more of an interview question to encourage discussion.

**Let's say we have the following two strings:**

```
str1 = 'helloworld'
str2 = 'helloldwor'
```

I want to be able to compare str1 to str2 and determine which characters in str2 are out-of-order, using the assumption that str1 is "correct". Also can assume that all characters in str2 are the same as str1 (str2 is simply a jumbled version of str1).

**EDIT:** In this case, I would say 'ld' is out of order. I define the 'out of order' substring as the smallest substring of str2 that if moved to the same location as that substring in str1, would make str1 == str2.

This question has been bothering me for a long time as it is something to figure out pretty easily visually, but I'm struggling to turn it into an algorithm of some kind.

**My attempt:**

```
def get_ooo(str1, str2):
#for potential options
local_set = Set()

#Loop from len(str1) to 1, splitting str2 by i to cover all possible substrings of str2
split_size = len(str1)
for i in range(len(str1),1,-1):
    print 'Iteration #' + str(len(str1) - split_size)

    #Try to find all substrings of str2 of length 'i' in str1
    for j in range(0,len(str1)-i):
        if str1.find(mid(str2,j,i)) < 0:
            #Failed to find substring in str1

            #Add to our local_set if it is a substring of all other failed substrings
            intersect = True
            for k in local_set:
                if k.find(mid(str2,j,i)) < 0:
                    intersect = False

            #If substring was a substring of all other failed substrings
            if intersect:
                #Add to local_set
                local_set.add(mid(str2,j,i))
                print mid(str2,j,i) + ' - FAIL, PASS'
            else:
                print mid(str2,j,i) + ' - FAIL, FAIL'
        else:
            print mid(str2,j,i) + ' - PASS'

#solution found?
best_option = ''
for option in local_set:
    if len(option) < len(best_option) or best_option == '':
        best_option = option
return best_option
```

Essentially, the logic I'm using is look for substrings of str2 in str1, starting from the largest possible substrings. When I find one that doesn't fit, I add it to a possible solution set. And if I find another substring that doesn't fit in str1, I only add it to the possible options if it is also a substring of all the other potential options. Therefore, the smallest sized substring in this set at the end will contain the first out-of-order character.

So, using this algorithm I always know where the out of order section **starts.**. However, I am clueless as to how to actually extract the section that is out of order.

I tried passing the strings to the function in reverse which gives me the first instance of a character out of a string from the back, which then gives me the full out-of-order substring here. But what if there are multiple sections that are out-of-order? Furthermore, based off my testing, this script only returns first instance of in str2 that a substring is out of order. For example:

```
str1 = 'helloworld'
str2 = 'hworldello'
```

Will return 'hw', telling me that the 'w' is where the string goes out of order. But in this example, it would make more sense if the 'ello' was out of order and not the 'world' substring since it is larger.

I've been staring at this question for more than a day now and decided its time to open it up to other opinions, especially since I feel like there has to be a better way. So what do you all think? Anyone have any brilliant ideas?

Comment: You can read about the Levenshtein distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: I think you should start with a formal definition of what you mean by "out of order".

Comment: @juanbits would Levenshtein distance be useful here? OP is looking for chunks of characters that are out of order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage recursion and search through the string both forwards and backwards to ensure the minimum sub-string is returned:

```
def find_substring_forwards(str1, str2, storage, index):

    global main1, main2

    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(str1, str2)):
        if x!=y and not storage: index = i
        expected_letter = main1[main1.index(''.join(storage))+len(storage)]
        if (x!=y or (expected_letter==x and main1.count(expected_letter)>1)) and index==i:
            storage.append(y)
            str2 = str2[:i] + str2[i+1:]
            if str1[:len(str2)]==str2: break
            return find_substring_forwards(str1, str2, storage, index)

    return ''.join(storage)

def find_substring_backwards(str1, str2, storage, index):

    global main1, main2

    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(str1, str2)):
        if x!=y and not storage: index = i
        if x!=y and index==i:
            storage.append(y)
            str2 = str2[:i] + str2[i+1:]
            if str1[:len(str2)]==str2: break
            return find_substring_backwards(str1, str2, storage, index)

    return ''.join(storage)

def out_of_order(str1, str2):

    x = ''.join(find_substring_forwards(str1, str2, [], None))
    y = ''.join(find_substring_backwards(str1[::-1], str2[::-1], [], None)[::-1])
    final = x if len(x)<=len(y) else y

    return final
```

A few test cases:

```
test_cases = [('helloworld','heworldllo','llo'),
            ('helloworld','hwoellorld','wo'),
            ('helloworld','hworldello','ello'),
            ('helloworld','helloldwor','ld'),
            ('helloworld','helloowrld','o'),
            ('helloworld','whelloorld','w')]

for test in test_cases:
    main1 = test[0]; main2 = test[1]
    x = out_of_order(main1, main2)
    print(main1, '|', main2)
    print('Expected:', test[2], '| Returned:', x, '\n')
```

Yields:

```
helloworld | heworldllo
Expected: llo | Returned: llo 

helloworld | hwoellorld
Expected: wo | Returned: wo 

helloworld | hworldello
Expected: ello | Returned: ello 

helloworld | helloldwor
Expected: ld | Returned: ld 

helloworld | helloowrld
Expected: o | Returned: o 

helloworld | whelloorld
Expected: w | Returned: w
```

**Explanation:**

We iterate through both strings at the same time, knowing that `str1` is the desired string. When we find a letter that does not match the correct position from `str1`, then we add that letter to storage and note the index. We then remove that letter from the string and repeat the process. We continue this recursive loop until the index at which we are removing letters changes. This indicates that we have reached the end of the "out-of-order" sub-string. To ensure we find the minimal sub-string (in terms of characters) we have to perform the same method in reverse (iterating backwards through the string). In the `out_of_order` function, we simply take the smaller of the two sub-strings, and if they are equal then we take the solution from iterating forwards through the strings (since either is technically correct).

**Update**

Had a previous issue with repeated letters in the string for the following test case:

```
('helloworld','heworldllo','llo')
```

Algorithm now checks whether the current letter being a candidate for removal from the string is actually the expected letter for the out-of-order sub-string. If it is, then add to the out-of-order sub-string `storage` container instead of ending the sub-string search prematurely. Also separated the functions for iterating through forwards and backwards for clarity and readability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this works pretty well, the only issue being in cases where characters from each string match up but we're still reading through the 'out-of-order' chunk.

For example, out_or_order('helloworld','heworldllo') will return 'wor'. This still works for me, however, since the "strings" I'm working on have unique characters so it shouldn't ever hit this case.

For the sake of the problem, I'm now looking into ways to work with non-unique characters for this and will update if I find anything.

Comment: Great! Would appreciate the upvote and checkmark if this helped!

Comment: Actually, according to your criteria, 'wor' would be correct. Are you expecting it to return 'llo'?

Comment: I would expect 'world' to be returned, this since 'world' is moved from the end to in between the 'hello' piece.

Comment: This is your criteria in your OP: "I define the 'out of order' substring as the smallest substring of str2 that if moved to the same location as that substring in str1, would make str1 == str2." Therefore, 'llo' would be correct. I see what you meant in your first comment, apologies for not understanding that at first. I'm working on this as well.

Comment: Oh whoops, good call. Thanks, I think your answer is sufficient for me but still is a fun little program to think about so I'll add more here if I come across any other good solutions.

Comment: I've made an update that should make this more robust.